# Cryolater without being a master lockpick

Tags: fallout-4

When first in the vault, I noticed the cryolater but couldn't get to it because it required master lockpicking; however, the cryolater can be retrieved without picking the lock.

> Dogmeat can be taken back to the vault and be used to search the area for items and get the Cryolater without needing any lockpicking skill. [Source](http://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/how-to-get-the-best-gun-in-fallout-4-right-away/)

As someone who is new to the Fallout series, is this method intentional or an exploit? If it is intentional, does it work for all locks? Is there any reason to become a master lockpicker in that case?

Comment: It's probably an "exploit" (as you say). Most of the time, Dogmeat would just lead you to the container with stuff, not actually get you what's inside.  Though, he'll only retrieve stuff on the ground you could actually see.  Probably he was able to get that because it can be seen.

Comment: I tried to do this recently and found that the companion you mentioned in the spoiler tag wasn't able to follow me to that location. Perhaps this has been patched now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a glitch; the only reason it worked is because the cryolater wasn't in a normal box. It was in a display case of sorts, so its world model was already present in the game. It's not like a normal box where the item's world model isn't present while in the box. If there are any other display case like boxes in the game where after being opened, the item is just sitting there to be picked up rather then from an item list like normal looting. I imagine the same glitch would work.

Comment: If this is a glitch, this is also liable to be fixed with future patches.